# Commutative property in Quotient ring does not work

Tags: ring-theory, cryptography, quotient-spaces

I was trying to implement Ring-LWE key exchange (not a real world implementation) just to see if I understood it correctly. I have been reading the theory fundamentals behind it but apparently it was not enough to make the implementation work. For my first implementation, I used the following parameters: $\mathbb{Z_{2^{23}-1}} / (x^{1024} + 1)$

**The basic idea** of Ring-LWE key exchange is the following:

> dimension = 4 (arbitrary)
>
> $A, S, S' = [rx^3 + rx^2 + rx + r,\\ rx^3 + rx^2 + rx + r,\\ rx^3 +
> rx^2 + rx + r,\\ rx^3 + rx^2 + rx + r]$   s.t. $r \in \mathbb{Z_{q}}$
>   (randomly generate)
>
> $B = AS + error$, $B' = AS' + error$
>
> $Shared key = SB' = S'B \to$ I did not use any error ($error =0$) but still shared key does not match. If there is some error (or noise) added to $B$, the we use reconciliation technique to make sure both parties achieve the same shared key.

I implemented the code (without any $error=0$ to test the commutative property):

**Sage code**:

```
from random import randint

def generate_matrix(dimention, modulus):
    array = []
    upper_limit = modulus * dimention

    for i in range(0, dimention):
        f = 0
        for j in range(0, dimention):
            f = f + (randrange(modulus, upper_limit) * x^j)

        array.append(f)

    return Matrix(array)

dimention = 128 # arbitrary
modulus = 40961
R = PolynomialRing(GF(65537), "X")
X = R.gen()
S = R.quotient(X^1024 + 1, "x")
x = S.gen()

A = generate_matrix(dimention, modulus)
Secret = generate_matrix(dimention, modulus)
Secret_ = generate_matrix(dimention, modulus)

B = A.transpose()*Secret
B_ = A.transpose()*Secret_

alice = Secret*B_
bob = Secret_*B

print alice == bob
```

As first I though maybe the Ring library in java is problematic , thus, I rewrite the code in sage. But still the shared key does not match. In order words, commutative property in Quotient ring does not work out.

**Links**:

- [Implementation #1](https://github.com/amir734jj/ringLWE), [ring library that it uses](http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/aks-primality/trunk/Poly.java) (java)
- [Implementation #2](https://gist.github.com/amir734jj/86efb6bf8897902317c7e1d8e73f8618) (sage)
- [Parameter choices according to this](https://youtu.be/BCmSzzQ2ges?t=7m56s)
- [Regev's basic reconciliation method](https://youtu.be/BCmSzzQ2ges?t=9m45s) (irrelevant to my question)

**Note**:
I asked this question on both [crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40309/trying-to-implement-ring-lwe-ke-to-understand-the-concept) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760772/trying-to-implement-ring-lwe-ke-to-understand-the-concept) but no answer so far.

Comment: Well, at first blush, since you have two things that appear to be matrices and you're multiplying them, I have to ask this: Do you realize that matrix multiplication is highly noncommutative? Two matrices over any ring (even a nice commutative ring) are likely not to commute.

Comment: I don't have any idea what the code you've written does, but it kind of looks like you're redefining $S$ somehow, and throwing away the original value...

Comment: @rschwieb that was just bad naming from my side. I fixed the code. Still no success.

Comment: Well... do you have any response to my first comment that will help me understand why I should expect these things to commute?

Comment: I understand, but I followed the algorithm here: https://youtu.be/BCmSzzQ2ges?t=8m53s

Comment: @rschwieb any help would be great.